# INDEX and AGGREGATE Function in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, indexing, find, aggregate

I'm trying to move an in cell formula to VBA, because otherwise it's always recalculating, even when I deactivate the excel option, it comes back when I reopen the file. That's why I want to move that formula to VBA, where it happens only when I press a button, which is much smarter.

I have a master table with data, which I aggregate and index and express it on another sheet in a table. -> column A to S are in the master table, in the aggregated table, I will only have column A,C,E,G,H,I,J,K,L,M and P

The formula I want to move to VBA is the following:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!$A:$S;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW(Endkontrolle!$A:$S)/((FIND($B$3;Endkontrolle!$F:$F;1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!$S:$S="x"));ROW()-32)-0;1);"")
```

Can somebody help me translate that formula to VBA script?

thank you very much

Comment: Do you have a data sample and an expected output? It would be easier to test any solution. Is a line like `Cells(1, 1) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!C1:C19,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!C1:C19)/((FIND(R3C2,Endkontrolle!C6,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!C19=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,1),"""")")` sufficient already?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447993/prevent-cell-from-being-calculated) solution?

Comment: Did you try the macro recorder? Sounds like a perfect scenario to learn some basic VBA and make your own non-volatile UDF

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey: Thanks for that. I implemented it and it works for 1 row. If I want to add the next data set from the main table, that does only repeat the content from previous row. How can I achieve, that it lists me more than 1 line of aggregated data?

Comment: @user2921653: i can't be sure about that. Your original formula has all the cell reference as absolute, therefore overall is not really able to "vary accordingly to its own change of position". Since i don't have your starting data and an expected result, i can't really reverse engeneer the formula. The only "weak" point to me is the `ROW()` part. Maybe that one is not changing in VBA. Then again: in your code you are focusing a series of columns on 2 rows. How is the formula supposed to react to change of columns and to change of rows?

Comment: @user2921653: answer are for answering. Stop posting an answer to add information to the question. You can edit the question itself instead. The data sample you've provided is incomplete: how can i relate the formula to that data sample? It has no coordinates. Even if i assume that `Date` is A column and colum `Date Range` is column S, which one is supposed to be column F? What's in cell B3 (which i guess it's in the "aggregated" sheet)? Why the expected result should be (if i've understood it correcly) only the first and the second row? Is the `x` in the `Date Range` column the only [...]

Comment: [...] condition? If so: what is the rest of the formula for then? What's its overall purpouse? Consider that i have only the information you've provided in this question. Could you immediatly recreate your file starting from just these informations? I know i can't; i can only speculate. Please provide better explanation of your problem, or i won't be able to actually help you. Once you've done that you might also want to post another comment (not an answer) referring to me so that it's reported in my inbox messages. That's because any answer (or edit to your question) are not reported to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub Button1_Click2()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngTable As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim StrColumnsIndex As String
    
    'A string is used to stores the index of the columns to be copied.
    StrColumnsIndex = "1;3;5;7;8;9;10;11;14;15;16"
    
    'RngTable is set as the range that will host the aggregated table.
    Set RngTable = Sheets("Aggregated sheet").Range("A33:K34") '< EDIT THIS LINE ACCORDGLY TO YOU NEED
    
    'Clearing RngTable.
    RngTable.ClearContents
    
    'Checking if StrColumnsIndex and RngTable are compatible.
    If UBound(Split(StrColumnsIndex, ";")) + 1 <> RngTable.Columns.Count Then
        MsgBox "The number of columns requested via StrColumnsIndex and the number of columns avaiable in RngTable do not match. Redefine the variables properly. The aggregated table will not be updated.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Variable mismatch"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Covering each cell in RngTable.
    For Each RngTarget In RngTable
        
        'The result is reported in each cell. The [row] element of the INDEX is obtained by subtracting _
        RngTable.Row from the RngTarget.Row and adding one. This way each row is properly reported. The _
        [col] element of the INDEX is obrained by splitting StrColumnsIndex using the difference between _
        the RngTarget.Column and RngTable.Column as index. This way each requested column as listed in _
        StrColumnsIndex is reported.
        'RngTarget.Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x""))," & RngTarget.Row - RngTable.Row + 1 & ")-0," & Split(StrColumnsIndex, ";")(RngTarget.Column - RngTable.Column) * 1 & "),"""")"
        RngTarget.Value = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x""))," & RngTarget.Row - RngTable.Row + 1 & ")-0," & Split(StrColumnsIndex, ";")(RngTarget.Column - RngTable.Column) * 1 & "),"""")")
        
        'If RngTarget contains nothing then it's assumed there are no more results to be reported and the macro is terminated.
        If RngTarget.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much! Is there a possibility to stop the calculation process once no more line was found? Actually it runs through all 20 rows, even if there is no data left to fill in.

Comment: Since the formula should report any empty cell as 0 while any "unfound" result should result in an empty cell, checking if any RngTarget is empty should be enouth to terminate the macro before its natural end. Code edited accordingly.

Comment: I tried it, but with the result that existing lines are not overwritten, because we stop in between, if the new data range only has 2 rows, while the previous selection had 5 lines. At the end I think the previous solution is good enough and I will enroll it with that. Thanks a lot for the help! much appreciated!

Comment: Never be satisfied. Just give me a minute and i'll edit the code.

Comment: Done. Try it and send a feedback. Only if satisfies you, you might mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: That exit once no more data is available works even better, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that. I implemented it and it works for 1 row. If I want to add the next data set from the main table, that does only repeat the content from previous row. How can I achieve, that it lists me more than 1 line of aggregated data?

Expected result:
it picks the relevant rows of data and lists it (different data according the find criteria)

Actual result:
it picks only 1 row and repeats it for the second line

Now I defined following code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()  
Cells(33, 1) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,1),"""")")
Cells(33, 2) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,3),"""")")
Cells(33, 3) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,5),"""")")
Cells(33, 4) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,7),"""")")
Cells(33, 5) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,8),"""")")
Cells(33, 6) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,9),"""")")
Cells(33, 7) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,10),"""")")
Cells(33, 8) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,11),"""")")
Cells(33, 9) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,14),"""")")
Cells(33, 10) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,15),"""")")
Cells(33, 11) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,16),"""")")


Cells(34, 1) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,1),"""")")
Cells(34, 2) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,3),"""")")
Cells(34, 3) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,5),"""")")
Cells(34, 4) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,7),"""")")
Cells(34, 5) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,8),"""")")
Cells(34, 6) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,9),"""")")
Cells(34, 7) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,10),"""")")
Cells(34, 8) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,11),"""")")
Cells(34, 9) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,14),"""")")
Cells(34, 10) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,15),"""")")
Cells(34, 11) = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX(Endkontrolle!A:S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Endkontrolle!A:S)/((FIND(B3,Endkontrolle!F:F,1)>0)*(Endkontrolle!S:S=""x"")),ROW()-32)-0,16),"""")")
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of the data in the main table "Endkontrolle":

| Date | Product | Employee | ... | Date Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22.04.2022 | MOTI | AKAH | ... | x |
| 23.04.2022 | MOTI_BG | AKAH | ... | x |
| 26.04.2022 | MOTI | AKAH | ... |  |

On the reporting page, I would like to list down up to 20 rows of Data, which are in the Date Range ('x') from the "Endkontrolle" worksheet.
In the upper example, it should list row 1+2, but not 3.

Comment: This is not an answer. You should edit your question to include these data.